# problem of searching strings that contain characters like [ with preg_replace

Tags: php

I'm trying to take a random string and use it in preg_replace. When $random takes a value that contains [ character php returns "Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset" error. Not just ] there are other characters cause error.

How can I solve this problem?

```
$random='asd[qwe';

preg_replace("/$random/", "replaced value", $text, 1);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape it. You can use [preg_quote](http://php.net/preg_quote):

```
$random = preg_quote('asd[qwe', '/');
preg_replace("/$random/", "replaced value", $text, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Certain characters need to be escaped. You can either setup an array of characters that need to be escaped, or escape them:

```
$random='asd\[qwe';

preg_replace("/$random/", "replaced value", $text, 1);
```

Should work.
<s>Here is an example of an array doing it:</s>

```
$random='asd[qwe(';

$escape = array('[', ']', ')', '(');
foreach ($escape as $esc) {
    $random = str_replace($esc, '\\' . $esc, $random);
}

preg_replace("/$random/", "replaced value", $text, 1);
```

I am sure that could be prettied up, but yea.

Removed as `preg_quote` is surely a better way.